# BitBucket: how to track a repo's branches in its Wiki repo?

Tags: git, github, mercurial, wiki, bitbucket

I have a (Mercurial) repo on BitBucket where I have a documentation directory to keep some simple markdown files

```
project
    .hg
    .hgignore
    src
        many files
    doc
        Home.md
```

This setup allows me to develop my documentation in sync with my code. I can write a small page documentating a new feature on a feature branch, and then merge both the source and the documentation into the master branch with a single commit.

However, the BitBucket wiki is a separate repository by itself (and I believe it's the same for GitHub). I can't figure out how to point it to my documentation. What works is to rename `doc` to `wiki` and make it a sub-repo inside `project`, but then it loses the branches from the main repo.

**So my question is**: Is there any way I can let my `wiki` track the `doc` subdirectory (with all its branches) from my main repository? Does Git or GitHub make it any easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem to be a way to track the wiki directory inside the project directory. But you can link to files in the project repository from the wiki. Example:

```
[README from default](https://bitbucket.org/owner/repository/src/tip/README.md)
[README from feat-aa](https://bitbucket.org/owner/repository/src/aa/README.md)
[Some other file](https://bitbucket.org/owner/repository/src/tip/doc/SOMEFILE.md)
```

You can even embed pictures hosted in the repository by putting "raw" in the url when using the `![]()` syntax:

```
![A image](https://bitbucket.org/owner/repository/raw/tip/image.png)
```

If you use the Creole syntax instead of markdown, there is even an [easier way](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Linking+to+a+File+from+a+Wiki+Page).

Comment: I tried this, but the relative links and pictures don't seem to work. I'll experiment more, and if it's the best I can do, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: To link to an image you can use the raw link: https://bitbucket.org/owner/project/raw/tip/picture.png and use the usual syntax: ! [ ] ( )

Comment: I'll add that to the answer.